# Group and sum values

Tags: pandas, group-by, sum

I have this df

```
'Item'   'Units Sold'

Item1      1
Item2      3
Item3      10
Item1      2
Item3      4
```

Then I want to group by item and sum the sold units:

```
Item   

'Item'   'Units Sold'

Item1      3
Item2      3
Item3      14
```

Comment: `df.groupby('item').sum()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Groupby.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
In [1167]: df = df.groupby('Item', as_index=False).sum()

In [1168]: df
Out[1168]: 
    Item  Units_Sold
0  Item1           3
1  Item2           3
2  Item3          14
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you!